# Cannot Find Function Contains in Object

Tags: javascript, contains

I'm getting the following error when I call the code listed below it.

`Cannot find function contains in object Is Patient Fasting?/# of Hours->Yes; 12 hours.`

My code:

```js
    var i = 0;

    var tempFastingQuest = "";
    var tempFastingAns = msg['OBR']['OBR.39'].toString();

    while (msg['NTE'][i] != null) {

           tempFastingQuest = msg['NTE'][i]['NTE.3']['NTE.3.1'].toString();

           if (tempFastingQuest.contains("Yes"))
                  tempFastingAns =  "Y";

           i = i + 1
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this JavaScript?  You need to tag your question with the name of the language you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is JavaScript: Strings don't have a `contains()` method, which the error clearly states.  Maybe you are looking for the `search()` method: `if (tempFastingQuest.search('Yes') > -1) ...`

Comment: Seeing how I've never written any scripting code before, nothing is "clearly" stated to me.  However, thanks for your search() suggestion as that did work.

Comment: Should be if (tempFastingQuest.search('Yes') > -1) as .search() will return 0 if the string searched for is at the start of the other string.